# Фураж и фуражка

Tags: однокоренные-слова

В детстве я была уверена, что слова "фураж" и "фуражка" родственные. А как обстоит дело на самом деле? Права я была или нет?
Заранее благодарю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Удивительно, но правы:
Слова фуражка (форменный головной убор) и фураж (корм для скота) восходят к одному источнику - французскому fourrage ("фураж, или корм для скота"). Фуражиры, то есть люди, занимавшиеся заготовкой кормов для армейских лошадей, носили особые головные уборы, которые в русском языке и назвали фуражками.
http://enc-dic.com/krylov/Furazhka-3995.html

Answer (score 2):

Фуражиры всегда были в обозе, а обоз - в хвосте движущейся армии. Мобильной связи не было, и фуражиры, отставшие от основных сил, были в постоянном напряжении: как бы не уйти в другую сторону и не пропустить поворот. Фуражиры были вынуждены часто прикладывать ладонь к  глазам, защищаясь от слепящих лучей солнца. Именно русскими фуражирами был придуман козырёк к военному головному головному убору, дававший возможность не прикладывать руку к глазам. До этого все головные уборы не имели козырьков и были своего рода бескозырками. Бескозырка и козырёк в совокупности образовали фуражку (от слова фуражир). Вскоре эта идея понравилась всем, кроме моряков, и пехота с кавалерией стали носить фуражки.